# WordPress add a line break in latest posts sidebar widget

Tags: wordpress

I configured the right sidebar to show the standard 'latest posts' widget.
Is it possible to add a line break after the title (everything marked in blue)?
So just like it is on accident with the second post.

[image]

Here is the html code:

```
<div class="span3 right tc-sidebar no-widget-icons">
       <div id="right" class="widget-area" role="complementary">
                <aside id="recent-posts-4" class="widget widget_recent_entries">        <h3 class="widget-title">Aktuelles</h3>     <ul>
                <li>
            <a href="http://website.de/weihnachtsfeier-des-roten-flures-am-22-12-2016/">Weihnachtsfeier des roten Flures am 22.12.2016</a>
                        <span class="post-date">10. Januar 2017</span>
                    </li>
                <li>
            <a href="http://website.de/so-sehen-sieger-aus/">So sehen Sieger aus</a>
                        <span class="post-date">13. Dezember 2016</span>
                    </li>
                <li>
            <a href="http://website.de/wir-sagen-dankeschoen/">Wir sagen »dankeschön«</a>
                        <span class="post-date">4. Februar 2016</span>
                    </li>
                <li>
            <a href="http://website.de/altes-zahngold-ermoeglichte-kletterwand-in-mes/">Altes Zahngold ermöglichte Kletterwand in MES</a>
                        <span class="post-date">4. Februar 2016</span>
                    </li>
                <li>
            <a href="http://website.de/sonnensegel-fuer-die-heissen-tage/">Sonnensegel für die heißen Tage</a>
                        <span class="post-date">4. Februar 2016</span>
                    </li>
            </ul>
    </aside>                    </div><!-- //#left or //#right -->
    </div><!--.tc-sidebar -->


    </div><!--.row -->
```

Comment: You can do this with CSS. Post the HTML Code of this picture or provide an link to your site.

Comment: It's just the screenshot of the sidebar widget from wordpress.

Comment: Yes I know :) I need the HTML output from this widget.

Comment: @AndyTschiersch please have a look at the edit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your CSS code:

```
.widget_recent_entries span.post-date {
    display: block;
}
```